# scroll header when scroll recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a header with an image and a RecyclerView with some items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ffffff">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

RelativeLayout is fixed on top of RecyclerView .
What I want is to scroll this header (RelativeLayout) up when scroll the RecyclerView .

---

Any ideas how to scroll header with RecyclerView?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

make your root layout a coordinator layout then make the RecyclerView Direct child of the coordinator layout. Wrap the scrollable content inside a AppBarLayout then apply the scroll behaviours. Try the following code this should help you.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
        android:background="#ffffff">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false" />

    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />



 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have toolbar, then fixed title content and then recyclerview. I want to scroll fixed content and recyclerview but don't want to scroll toolbar. How can I do it?